# An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, exception, viewbag

Controller:

```
 var staffList = (from st in db.tbl_UserRole
                             join usr in db.tbl_User on st.UserId equals usr.Id
                             select new
                             {
                                 _name = usr.Name,
                                 _email = usr.Email,
                             }
                             ).ToList();
            ViewBag.UL = staffList;
```

View:

i'm unable to solve this error 
on "@item._name" it give an exception "'object' does not contain a definition for '_name'"

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.UL) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item._name 
    </td>
    <td>
        @item._email
    </td>
```

}

Comment: try after removing _ before name and email

Comment: i try but again same error

Comment: do you getting correct data in Viewbag.UL in debugging?

Comment: Yes i'm getting a correct data

Comment: @{
    var results = ViewBag.UL;
}

Comment: foreach (var item in results {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item._name 
    </td>
}
try this way

Comment: no it's not working again same error :(